# What is the timezone followed by Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

For example, when the **Daily Installs By Device** is shown as a graph, it mentions the time period as **for Jan 20, 2014 - Jan 21, 2014**. What is the timezone of these dates?

So, what is the timezone followed?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In case anyone comes looking for the answer here:

I emailed the Play Store support and they replied that the timezone followed by the Developer Console is **Pacific Standard Time (PST)**.

Comment: Can I somehow change it to european time?

Comment: At the moment it can't be changed... :(

Answer (score -2):

The Google Play statistics are updated every 24 hours. 
I think they follow UTC but there is no official source that its true. Check this out : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/2AR46HOITig